# The HTTP request to *.svc has exceeded the allotted timeout. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Tags: silverlight, wcf, timeout

I have been developing a Silverlight application using WCF.

The problem is that sometimes it throws an exception stating:

"The HTTP request to 'http://localhost:1276/Foo.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."

So how do I increase the timespan? Some have suggested the usage of receive time out as below in web config and in service.client config file

```
 <bindings>
      <customBinding >
        <binding  name="customBinding0" receiveTimeout="02:00:00" >
          <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647" maxSessionSize="2147483647" />


          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered"/>

        </binding>
      </customBinding>      
    </bindings>
```

what would be the maximum value for the receiveTimeout property?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I imagine the issue is not that your ReceiveTimeout is beyond the maximum value for that setting, as the MaxValue of a TimeSpan is over 10 million days. Instead, I think the settings are just not taking effect.

You should try increasing the timeout values on both the server and the client-side:

On the server (in your web.config)

```
<binding name="customBinding0" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
```

On the client (in your ServiceReferences.ClientConfig)

```
<binding name="CustomBinding_DesignOnDemandService" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
```

Comment: Exactly happened with me, I changed the setting in web.config and it was not reflecting. the reason was my application was setting values from its own setup file "not from web.config"

Answer (score 7):

The HTTP request to  has exceeded the allotted timeout. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Three places to set time values to fix this issue…

1. Web.Config

   ```
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" />
   ```

   (this is seconds, so here it’s 10min).   More info on httpRuntime here.
2. On your Web.Config Binding Elements

   ```
   <binding name="customBinding123"     receiveTimeout="00:10:00"     sendTimeout="00:10:00"     openTimeout="00:10:00"     closeTimeout="00:10:00" />
   ```
3. On your ServerReferences.ClientConfig binding elements within the system.serviceModel

   ```
   <binding name="CustomBinding"     receiveTimeout="00:10:00"     sendTimeout="00:10:00"     openTimeout="00:10:00"     closeTimeout="00:10:00" />
   ```

Comment: All bindings in web config, client config as well as the executionTimeout are set to 10 minutes, yet I still get the timeout at exactly 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

Some days ago we got the same error message. I found this thread, but before we started to increase the different timeout properties, we checked the antivirus software of the client machine: it was NOD. The newer NOD (and maybe other AVs) has port filter/block possibility. We turned off the 80/443 port blocking, and the client connected without any timeout error message.